# Confused about reported speech and reporting speech

Tags: spoken-english, reported-speech

Look at the following example:

> David said, “I’m baking a chocolate cake for you.’’

Some says the sentence between the inverted commas is called reporting speech. 
and some says it reported speech.

Which is correct? why?

Answer (score 1):

Neither is correct as that is direct speech.

> David said that he was baking a cake for me

Would be the equivalent reported speech.

Reporting speech is not correct at all.